# Difference between changing permission Recursively or without Recursively

Tags: chmod, recursive

What is the difference in the command
`chmod 777 *`
and `chmod -R 777 *`
changing permission recursively or normally?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have the following directory structure:

```
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 a

./a:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 b

./a/b:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 c

./a/b/c:
total 0
```

With just `chmod 777 *` the permissions of all files in the current directory are set to 0777. However, files in subdirectories are not affected, i.e. `a/` will have permissions set 0777 but not `a/b` or `a/b/c` etc.:

```
$ chmod 777 *
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 a

./a:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 b    <=== Note

./a/b:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 c    <=== Note

./a/b/c:
total 0
```

This is where recursion strikes: with `chmod -R 777 *` all files and directories in all subdirectories of the current directory will be affected:

```
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 a

./a:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 b    <=== Note

./a/b:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 user users 4096 Aug  2 14:05 c    <=== Note

./a/b/c:
total 0
```

Note: If you use bash, then the meaning of "all files" depends on the value of `dotglob`, see bash(1); likewise for other shells.